# How to set default tracking with Microtype

Tags: luatex, microtype

using LuaLaTeX engine (TeXLive 2015) and Microtype package (2.6a), I am trying to set the default tracking (letterspacing) for all italic fonts (actually, just one font in some size range would suffice), so that I do not have to wrap every `\textit` in `\textls`. So far no success.

I am trying to use `\DeclareMicrotypeSet` and `\UseMicrotypeSet`, however I cannot (it causes error) use thus defined set in the `\SetTracking` command, and when I use for this command just the general definition of italic font (`encoding = *, shape = it*, size = 8-15`) it only works within `\textls`; it does NOT work by default.

Would anyone know what am I doing wrong or what am I missing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, is there anyone here who would agree with the microtype documentation that the package configuration is “straightforward”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a minimal example featuring customised tracking for all italic fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}         % 1. Enable tracking
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{italics} % 2. Declare which fonts should 
  { encoding = *, shape = it* }          %    receive tracking adjustment
\SetTracking                             % 3. Specify the tracking amount
  { encoding = *, shape = it* }          %    for the fonts
  {200}
\begin{document}
abc \textit{def} hij
\end{document}
```